# Remove Range of items with HashSet

Tags: c#, hashset

I am using an HashSet.

I am looking for a way to remove range of items from the beginning of the HashSet.

With `List` it can be done with `RemoveRange`

**Example**

Removes 10 items from the beginning:

```
dinosaurs.RemoveRange(0, 10);
```

Can this be done with HashSet?

**[Edit]** The the order of the HashSet does not matter since it contains only random strings.

Comment: The items in a hashset are unordered, so the idea of an index or a sequence of items is nonsensical for that data structure.

Comment: No - you have to remove them one at a time.

Comment: While going through documentation in MSDN, only function available in hashset to remove multiple items is RemoveWhere(Predicate<T> match). If Dinosaur has some property (e.g. size) then multiple items can be removed using RemoveWhere (e.g. dinosaurs.RemoveWhere(d => d.size > 6)).

But removing a range of items is not supported by HashSet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361254(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet` stores unique pieces of data (under the hood, the storage is identical to the keys stored in a `Dictionary`) so it doesn't make much sense to remove "the first" 10 items, since they'll be effectively randomly ordered, only not actually random for most needs.

If you need to order them more appropriately for a random, `OrderBy` can do that:

```
var r = new Random();
foreach(var dinoToRemove in dinosaurs
    .OrderBy(x => r.Next())
    .Take(10))
{
    dinosaurs.Remove(dinoToRemove);
}
```

If you really are determined to remove the first ten, you could also use an iterator with `RemoveWhere`

```
var count = 0;
dinosaurs.RemoveWhere(x => count++ < 10);
```

Comment: I do not care about order, it's just an HashSet of random stuff anyway :) Great answer.

Comment: in which case you may want to use a List, since there's a (small) performance cost to calculating those Hashes

Comment: Ended up using a **Queue**. But your answer does solve the question if anyone else would need it. Yes, `List` would work for ranged Delete. Just wanted performance, but sometimes performance has a cost of flexibility.

Comment: Why does `count++ < 10` work? It is somehow translating the variable name "count" to the `count` property of each member?

Comment: As I said, that would remove the first ten members, thus I'm capturing the `count` declared outside the lambda and not actually caring what's in `x`. This is also more memory efficient than just making anew HashSet after using `Skip(10)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use LINQ and pass the results to a HashSet constructor:

```
var filteredList = new HashSet<Dinosaur>
(
    originalList.Skip(10)
);
```

As Servy notes, a HashSet may not be ordered, so you might want to get an ordered enumerable before you skip 10.

```
var filteredList = new HashSet<Dinosaur>
(
    originalList
        .OrderBy( x => x.Foo )
        .Skip(10)
);
```

If you don't want to instantiate a new HashSet (i.e. you want to remove items from the existing instance) you will need to do that one by one.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using **Queue**.  And removing first element if Queue exceeds the allowed amount.   Not Ranged, but good enough. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Consider using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301(v=vs.110).aspx instead @Dror .